# How to get the last 4 characters in a string - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this string in my database like `12-12-2067`. I want to only display the last 4 words in the string `2067` in my view. How do i achieve this ?

```
$get_string = Item::all()->first();


<p>{{get_string}}</p>
```

Comment: Is it always a date like that 12-12-2067 ??

Comment: @Maraboc, it is not a date, it is actually a string that i generate with an algorithm

Comment: Is it always separated with - ??

Comment: if you have alway the - as separator you can do `$parts = explode('-', $get_string);` and then use `$parts[2]` or `explode('-', $get_string)[2]` !!

Comment: @Maraboc  i am trying to do this in the view not the controller

Comment: yes you can do {{ explode('-', $get_string)[2] }} inthe view

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use:

```
substr ($getstring->string, -4)
```

Because of (-) it will start form the end of the string and it will take the next 4 characters.

Take care that first() it will return an object and not the string you want.

Comment: can't i do it in the view?. yes i am aware of the `first`

Comment: yes of course you can try {{ substsr ($getstring->string, -4)}}

Comment: Did it worked? :)

Comment: "Call to undefined function substsr()"

Comment: is substr() not substsr()  :)

sorry I will edit my answer!

Comment: This is working in a table from one of my view:

Answer (score 2):

Please read the manual [substr](http://php.net/substr).

```
$str = substr($str, -4);
```

Answer (score 0):

string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

$dynamicstring = "12-07-2017";
$newstring = substr($dynamicstring, -4);